# Given the vector field $F(x,y,z) = (z\sin{x}, yz\cos{x}, x^2 + y^2)$, calculate the flux $\int_S F\cdot \hat{n}\,dS$ through a paraboloid.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Note: This question has been asked before, but not by me. I did not find any answers sufficient enough to help me resolve the problem. The statement of the problem is as follows:

Given the vector field $F(x,y,z) = (z\sin{x}, yz\cos{x}, x^2 + y^2)$, calculate the flux $\int_S F\cdot \hat{n}\,dS$ through the paraboloid $S = \{(x,y,z) : z = -3(x^2+y^2) + 3, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal pointing in the positive $z$-direction.

What was suggested previously: If we have some function of $f(x,y)$ the outward normal in the positive $z$-direction is $(-f_x, -f_y, 1)$. In this case, $\hat{n} = (-z\cos{x}, yz\sin{x}, 1)$ Great, this simplifies things, then $F \cdot \hat{n} = -z^2\cos^2{x} + yz^2\cos^2{x} + x^2 + y^2$. Wait, that looks horrible. Is there some algebraic manipulations I am missing here? I'm also not really seeing an easy change of coordinates, since we have have quadratic AND trigonometric terms in $x$.

If we try the divergence theorem, $\nabla \cdot F = 2z\cos{x}$ and coordinates for the paraboloid and a trigonometric function of $x$. Any suggestions? It's not valid to take the volume integral $$\int_0^3 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 2z\cos{x} dxdydz$$ right? This is possible to evaluate, but I doubt it's correctness.

The last possibility I see is a typo in $F$, where a minus sign on the $y$ coordinate fixes everything by making the divergence 0.

Comment: If you try to apply the divergence theorem and convert the surface integral into a volume integral, this will give you the flux through the paraboloid and the circular bottom. You'll need to subtract the flux through the bottom to get the right answer.

Comment: Ok, so entertaining the thought that there is a sign wrong, and $divF$ evaluates to 0, the flux through the bottom of the volume is pretty easy, since the bottom is the unit circle with normal vector $(0,0,-1)$ (since it's outward). Then $$\int_S F \cdot n dS = -\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r^2 rdrd\theta = -2\pi \cdot \frac14 = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ Subtracting this from 0, we get that the original flux integral equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Any errors there?